# How to run apache flink streaming job continuously on Flink server

Tags: java, postgresql, streaming, apache-flink

**Hello**,
I written code for streaming job where as source and target is a PostgreSQL database. I used JDBCInputFormat/JDBCOutputFormat to read and write the records([Referenced example](https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-streaming)). 
Code:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment environment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    environment.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);

    JDBCInputFormatBuilder inputBuilder = JDBCInputFormat.buildJDBCInputFormat()
            .setDrivername(JDBCConfig.DRIVER_CLASS)
            .setDBUrl(JDBCConfig.DB_URL)
            .setQuery(JDBCConfig.SELECT_FROM_SOURCE)
            .setRowTypeInfo(JDBCConfig.ROW_TYPE_INFO);

    SingleOutputStreamOperator<Row> source = environment.createInput(inputBuilder.finish())
            .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new AscendingTimestampExtractor<Row>() {
                @Override
                public long extractAscendingTimestamp(Row row) {
                    Date dt = (Date) row.getField(2);
                    return dt.getTime();
                }
            })
            .keyBy(0).window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))
            .fold(null, new FoldFunction<Row, Row>(){
                @Override
                public Row fold(Row row1, Row row) throws Exception {
                    return row;
                }
            });

    source.writeUsingOutputFormat(JDBCOutputFormat.buildJDBCOutputFormat()
            .setDrivername(JDBCConfig.DRIVER_CLASS)
            .setDBUrl(JDBCConfig.DB_URL)
            .setQuery("insert into tablename(id, name) values (?,?)")
            .setSqlTypes(new int[]{Types.BIGINT, Types.VARCHAR})
            .finish());
```

This code is executing correctly but **not running continuously on Flink server**(Select query is executing only once.)
Expected to **run continuously** on flink server.

Comment: Have you checked this Iteration Operators https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/batch/index.html#iteration-operators

Comment: Thanx Chengzhi. It works.

Comment: It iterate over the result stream continuously but query executing only one time not multiple times.

Comment: How does your code look like? Maybe good to check this example: https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-batch/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/examples/scala/clustering/KMeans.scala#L88

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you have to define your own Flink Source or JDBCInputFormat, since the one you use here will stop the SourceTask while fetching all results from DB. One way to solve this is create your own jdbc input format based on `JDBCInputFormat`, trying to re-execute the SQL query while reading the last row from DB in `nextRecord`.